# My google site does not add CSS til after the elements

Tags: html, css, google-sites

My main issue is that my CSS does not load with the elements.  I'm placing my CSS/HTML insde the HTML boxes as a lot of styling is not allowed directly in the HTML.  There are a bunch of other frustrating things with Google Sites but this is what I need help with right now.

I'll navigate/refresh my page and all of my elements will display without CSS.  Then after a few seconds the CSS is applied and things look how I want.

How do I get the CSS to load correctly?  I can't have my menus and object load looking all crazy.

Here is a random example of code that does this (anything I've put into these boxes does this)

```
<style type="text/css">
span
{
    float:left;
    width:0.7em;
    font-size:400%;
    font-family:algerian,courier;
    line-height:80%;
}
</style>
<p>
    <span>T</span>he first letter in ths paragraph is styled
    with CSS to be 400% larger than the rest of the text.
</p>
```

UPDATE:  I've spoken with a Google Apps rep and they opened a ticket as the css not loading is a bug.  No word on the time frame but they are working on it.

Comment: It might be somewhere else in your code http://jsfiddle.net/6eGFr/

Comment: The code is just an example.  These boxes are within the page.  It's a google sites thing that is doing it.  Maybe the Caja compiler is messing with it. I'm not sure.

Comment: lol, it just seems so odd, if it's only 1 thing i'd go for `<span style="float:left;width:0.7em;` etc, but if your entire page seems like crap on load I'd take a look at other Google sites and see how they done it. Other than the weird HTML and use of `<br>` in menu's that could be perfect `<li>`s they open ok for me. Maybe it's admin thing, try to look at it from another browser or logged out... not familiair with Gsites but there's nothing wrong with the code you have.

Comment: Why did you have to use this specific example? Don't you know how hard it is to not remark you can easily dispense with the span?

Comment: Have you tried placing the styles in the `<header>`, instead of in the `<body>`?

Comment: The HTML boxes wrap the code in their own element through Caja.  So no <body> or <header> sections are needed.  I have tried to add the header sections and format as I would a full HTML page but it still loaded the elements before applying the css styling :(

Comment: @apohl 1) I sincerely hope you mean `<head>` instead of `<header>`, and 2) the OP said they couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and a workaround can be

```
<style type="text/css">
.show-on-load {
    display: block !important;
}
span
{
    float:left;
    width:0.7em;
    font-size:400%;
    font-family:algerian,courier;
    line-height:80%;
}
</style>
<p class="show-on-load" style="display: none;">
    <span>T</span>he first letter in ths paragraph is styled
    with CSS to be 400% larger than the rest of the text.
</p>
```

This way the content doesn't display until the CSS is loaded. Unfortunately, I can't use this workaround myself because I have to support IE8 and style tags don't load at all there.

Edit: use opacity instead so IE8 is supported

Comment: I've spoken with a google representative and this is a bug that they are now working on.  Hopefully they will have a solution for it soon.